# How do I fix my Unusual?

Tags: team-fortress-2

For a long time, orbitals like the Circling Peace Sign effect and Circling TF2 Logo will tend to increase their radius for no reason. This can result in the effect "not" being on my hat, but about 30 meters away, orbiting around me. Is there a way to prevent it, and if not, is there a way to revert it if it happens?

This glitch beneath this fixed itself when I got back on the next day, but it would be nice if it could be reverted without having to restart TF2.

> Today I acquired a hat with the effect Eerie Orbiting Fire. I love this effect, so I was looking forward to seeing it when I taunted. But, when I did, the fire ball was not there. I taunted it again, and it was. After that, I walked forward a couple of steps, and taunted. The effect was at the place I last taunted and was slowing orbiting towards me. Is there a way to fix it and make sure it stays around my head?

Comment: Have you changed the position of the effect?

Comment: Yes, but that did not change anything besides change its Y location, where it was still was not where it should have been.

Comment: If you uncheck "Adjust Unusual", does the same issue occur again?

Comment: Yes, I already tried changing the slider and unchecking the box.

Comment: Update : When I logged on this morning and taunted, my Eerie Fire was behaving normaly. I am going to assume that it was just my connection or the server I was on. BUT, the problem with the Orbitals has been around for ever.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your unusual effect not appearing is a common glitch known as an orphaned effect. The same glitch is also the reason you can see unusual effects floating around a map. There have been updates that have addressed it but there hasn't been any definitive fix yet.